# How to merge first and last name field on registration page in opencart 3.0.2?

Tags: forms, merge, opencart

Opencart 3.0.2
I want to merge the First and Last Name form field to make it Full Name without disabling or rename any of these form fields on the registration page.

Eg. First Name [space] Last Name

In case I disable Last Name field and rename first Name field to Full Name then on admin side Full Name will be assigned to the First name and Last Name will be empty which is not right when editing order or customer.

I searched in google and opencart forum no helpful found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this trick

replace the two form-groups of firstname and lastname by this code:

```
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-fullname">{{ entry_fullname }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="fullname" value="{{ fullname }}" placeholder="{{ entry_fullname }}" id="input-fullname" class="form-control" />
        {% if error_fullname %}
        <div class="text-danger">{{ error_fullname }}</div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="firstname" id="input-firstname">
<input type="hidden" name="lastname" id="input-lastname">

<script>
$('#input-fullname').on('input', function(){
    thisValue = $(this).val().split(' ');
    if (thisValue.length > 1 ) {
        $('#input-firstname').val(thisValue.shift());
        $('#input-lastname').val(thisValue.join(' '));
    }
});
</script>
```

then add this validation rule to "catalog/controller/account/register.php" in function validate()

```
if (count(explode(' ', trim($this->request->post['fullname']) )) < 2) {
    $this->error['fullname'] = $this->language->get('error_fullname');
}
```